# gcc: fatal error: input file 'expthread' is the same as output file compilation terminated

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I'm student in university.
[image]

To do the assignment, I installed Linux using Ubuntu for the first time, and I wrote down the file given as an example and compiled it, but this error keeps coming out. Why does it come out and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: How did you compile it?

Comment: i wrote that in vscode and just complie with gcc complier

Comment: Yes, but how exactly did you compile it with gcc?